# map для двух списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два списка:

```
list1 = ('obj0', 'obj2', 'obj4', 'obj5')
list2 = ('obj0', 'obj1', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5')
```

Из него я получаю

```
joined = list(set(list1 + list2))
```

Хочется получить список кортежей вида

```
(('obj0', 'obj0'), ('', 'obj1'), ('obj2', ''), ('', 'obj3'), ('obj4', 'obj4'), ('obj5', 'obj5'))
```

С помощью for и if...else я могу сделать требуемое, но хочется знать, как можно сделать такое с помощью map.

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = ('obj0', 'obj2', 'obj4', 'obj5')
list2 = ('obj0', 'obj1', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5')
max_n = 5  # Можно посчитать на основе максимального значения в obj* 

items = []
for i in range(max_n + 1):
    val = f'obj{i}'
    items.append((
        val if val in list1 else '',
        val if val in list2 else ''
    ))
print(items)
# [('obj0', 'obj0'), ('', 'obj1'), ('obj2', ''), ('', 'obj3'), ('obj4', 'obj4'), ('obj5', 'obj5')]
```

Можно обернуть в функцию и использовать `map`:

```
def apply(i, list1, list2):
    val = f'obj{i}'
    return (
        val if val in list1 else '',
        val if val in list2 else ''
    )

list1 = ('obj0', 'obj2', 'obj4', 'obj5')
list2 = ('obj0', 'obj1', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5')
max_n = 5  # Можно посчитать на основе максимального значения в obj*

items = list(map(lambda i: apply(i, list1, list2), range(max_n + 1)))
print(items)
# [('obj0', 'obj0'), ('', 'obj1'), ('obj2', ''), ('', 'obj3'), ('obj4', 'obj4'), ('obj5', 'obj5')]
```

---

**PS.**

О том как найти максимальное значение для перебора:

```
list1 = ('obj0', 'obj2', 'obj4', 'obj5')
list2 = ('obj0', 'obj1', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5')
joined = set(list1 + list2)

max_v = max(joined, key=lambda x: int(x[3:]))
print(max_v)
# obj5

max_n = int(max_v[3:])
print(max_n)
# 5
```

Comment: Спасибо, @gil9red, за развернутый ответ!

Comment: @Boris, пожалуйста :)